# MapBox causes Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: ios, swift, memory, mapbox

I am using mapbox to show the location of the place in my app. But I every time I had such a problem. When i close the View with map memory is still being busy. And after 4 of 5 opening this view my app crashed with "Terminated due to memory issue". How can i solve it? May be there are some way to clear memory ofter closing this View with map? I am using Swift

Comment: Yes. With the use of MapBox you will get this issue sometime or later. Because too much memory it utilizes. When you open multiple times you will get this problem. You need to figure out the objects you are creating and should release them by yourself. That's the only way you can solve this.

Comment: may be u can say how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this memory leak is that the view controller might have not been deallocated.
You can check whether the view controller where you are using the map box map is properly getting deallocated or not.

You can use the below code in a view controller to know if that has been deallocated when you dismiss/pop a view controller or change a root view controller where you have the map.

```
deinit {
   print("Memory to be released soon")
}
```

SOLUTION:
If the above code is not getting called, check for any delegate for which there might be a strong reference. You can fixit by changing that to a weak reference as shown below.

```
protocol DealCellDelegate: class {
    func method()
}

weak var delegate: MyViewControllerDelegate?
```

Checkout "Bonus: View Controller - weak delegate" section in https://samwize.com/2016/05/30/finding-retain-cycle-with-instruments/ for more information.